# REACT- Storing data that needs to be updated frequently as a global variable instead of using setState() - not recommended?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, scroll, global-variables

I am trying to determine the best way to increase performance in my `onScroll` event listener within my React Component. I have a simple listener which tracks the `scrollY` To keep track of this (cross-browser), I have the following:

```
handleScroll = (event) => {
    let scrollTop = Math.max(window.pageYOffset, document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop)
}
```

Now, I need to determine whether the user is scrolling up or down. I was hoping that the actual `event` object would have some kind of flag, but I've mostly seen people suggesting keeping track of the previous `scrollTop` and comparing with each iteration of the function.

I am wondering, what are the perf impacts of calling `this.setState({scrollY: scrollTop})` every single time my scroll handle is running? When I scroll down the page using the scrollbar, my event handler will fire off something like 50-70 times. I know that `React.Component.setState` does have some async/batching behaviors - and calling it 50 times seems excessive.

So instead of calling `setState`, I was thinking about just storing a `global variable` in the component - I imagine that updating a single var 50 times would be less impactful. I was also considering throttling the function, but can I throttle the function if I want it to be relatively sensitive and not miss scroll events?

This is basically what I'm looking to do:

```
// Global Variable ...
let avoidNameCollidePrevScrollTop

class WatchMeScroll extends Component {
  handleScroll = (event) => {
    let scrollTop = Math.max(window.pageYOffset, document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop)

    if (avoidNameCollidePrevScrollTop && scrollTop > avoidNameCollidePrevScrollTop && this.state.scrollDir !== 'Scrolling Down') { 
             this.setState({
                 scrollDir: 'Scrolling Down'
             })
         }

    if (avoidNameCollidePrevScrollTop && scrollTop < avoidNameCollidePrevScrollTop && this.state.scrollDir !== 'Scrolling Up') { 
             this.setState({
                 scrollDir: 'Scrolling Up'
             })
        }
    // { Handle UI changes by checking if user is scrolling Up/Down into different sections of the app using Ref.getBoundingClientRect() }
    // Set ScrollTop position for next iteration of handleScroll - avoiding setState firing excessively
    avoidNameCollidePrevScrollTop = scrollTop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! `setState()` is an async operation but after every `setState` call your component re-renders and eventually it can have performance issues when called very frequently like by a scroll handler.

Ideally, if changing a variable has nothing to do with updating the DOM (more specifically virtual DOM) then it shouldn't be kept as a state variable rather it can made class variable like

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.someVar = someDefaultValue;
```

and this variable `someVar` can be accessed anywhere inside component using `this.someVar`.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that AFAIK a component will only re-render if either state or props change, and since React 16 with Fiber I’m not really sure keeping the variable in the state will really be noticeable. If somebody has benchmarked this I’d be more than interested in learning the details, though.